# Using method return value as argument vs setting class variable in one method and using it as an argument of another

Tags: php, function, oop

I was wondering what are the pros and cons of these 2 programming styles, is it just a matter of taste or is one the desired way?

using a method return value as an argument for another method :

```
public function add($data) 
{
    $this->uploadFilesToPreflight(
        $this->addOrderFilesToDB(
            $data['shop'],
            $data['filesData']
        )
    );
}
```

VS setting a protected class variable in method 1 and using it as method 2 argument:

```
public function add($data) 
{
    //does some stuff and sets $orderFilesArray
    $this->addOrderFilesToDB($data['shop'], $data['filesData']);

    $this->uploadFilesToPreflight($this->orderFilesArray);
}
```

Comment: In the first case, you do not reserve memory for the `orderFilesArray`. The second is good, when you need to store that array for later use.

Comment: It's just stylistic preference. You could also leave out the argument to `uploadFilesToPreflight` if it always uses `$this->orderFilesArray`.

Comment: @lolka_bolka that actually not completely true, because the return value of `addOrderFilesToDB` will be passed as a new variable and thus use the nearly amount of memory as if you define it as a property.

Comment: @gries Yes, but after complete the operation, the memory released, isn't it? While if you create a property, it will hold that memory. Please tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: @lolka_bolka yes that is actually correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is, what is the class supposed to be? And does the class have a state?

If the class is supposed to be a service where `add($data)` can be called multiply times and the behavior should not change the first option would be better.

If the class has a state and it's behavior is supposed to change by call `add($data)` then the second option is fine but you have to be aware that this can cause side-effects if the class has other methods that rely on `$this->orderFilesArray`.

To provide a better answer on what option is best, you would have to post a broader context of the class.